# use TCPDF in threads that created with pthreads

Tags: php, pthreads, tcpdf

I want use`TCPDF` in threads that created with `pthreads` in `php`.
When i use `TCPDF` this **error appears:**

> "Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER in ..."

how i must resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER` is a super global, and globals are not copied by pthreads when creating new threads.

```
<?php
class ServerAwareThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct(array $server) {
        $this->server = (array) $server;
    }

    public function run() {
        $_SERVER = array_merge(
            $_SERVER ?: [], $this->server);

        /* show that it's super global */
        $this->other();
    }

    public function other() {
        var_dump($_SERVER);
    }
}

$thread = new ServerAwareThread($_SERVER);

$thread->start() && $thread->join();
?>
```

Simply pass in `$_SERVER` as a dependency and setup `$_SERVER` in the new thread.